# Degree Angle and Vecorization with Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib, vectorization, degrees

Every time I run the script on a new dataset the angle lines move around. I want to have two lines angled at 345 (green line) and 330 (red line) degrees respectively each time a new dataset is read in.

What is wrong with my code?

Results should look something like this:

[image: What I'm trying to achive looks like this every tim a new dataset with similar characteristic is added]

#### 1st Data Set

```
data = np.array([10.79,10.87,10.94,10.95,11,11.5,10.89,11.45,11.94,12.17,12.45,12.09,13.65,13.5,13.25,13.18,13.28,
             13.45,13.81,13.8,14.08,14.09,14.48,14.5,14.08,14.54,14.6,15.48,16,17.049999,17.219999,16.99,
             17.23,17.200001,17.110001,18.190001,23.540001,22.25,21.15,22.09,22.85,21.4,21.41,20.780001,18.84,
             18.389999,18.09,18.280001,17.959999,21.969999,21.120001,20.25,19.879999,21.309999,21.84])
```

#### 2nd Data Set

```
data = np.array([12.44,12.02,12.58,12.09,12,11.98,12.19,11.75,11.44,11.4,10.68,10.46,10.95,10.6,11.44,
             10.6,10.41,10.3,11.45,12.5,12.65,11.62,11.45,11.16,10.8,12.5,12.23,13.99,12.49,13.49,12.69,12.72,
             12.81,13.1,12.89,13.50,13.35])
```

#### Script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import signal

for number in data:

signal_max = (data > np.roll(data,1)) & (data > np.roll(data,-1))
signal_min = (data < np.roll(data,1)) & (data < np.roll(data,-1))


xm = np.argmax(data)
ym = np.amax(data)

angle1 = 345 # green
angle2 = 330 # red

x1, y1 = xm + len(data)-xm, ym + math.tan(angle1 * math.pi/180) * len(data)-xm
x2, y2 = xm + len(data)-xm, ym + math.tan(angle2 * math.pi/180) * len(data)-xm

plt.plot( [ xm, x1 ], [ym, y1 ], '-', color='g')
plt.plot( [ xm, x2 ], [ym, y2 ], '-', color='r')
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you should be careful of when visualising angles on your plot is the aspect ratio of the plot. If the aspect ratio of the plot is not equal, then the angles visualised will not look like you expect them to!

You can tidy up the plotting of the angles as:

```py
angle1 = np.deg2rad(345) # green
angle2 = np.deg2rad(330) # red

x1, y1 = np.cos(angle1), np.sin(angle1)
x2, y2 = np.cos(angle2), np.sin(angle2)

plt.plot( [ xm, xm + x1 ], [ym, ym + y1 ], '-', color='g')
plt.plot( [ xm, xm + x2 ], [ym, ym + y2 ], '-', color='r')
```

To ensure an equal aspect ratio you can use `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')`

If you'd like to alter the length of the lines you can introduce a scale variable as:

```py
scale = 2
x1, y1 = scale * np.cos(angle1), scale * np.sin(angle1)
x2, y2 = scale * np.cos(angle2), scale * np.sin(angle2)
```

So, if you'd like the lines to reach to the end of the data you can set

`scale = data.size - xm`

Comment: That worked like a miracle thank you...however the two lines become very short and doesnt extend all the way to the latest data point as it used to

Comment: Hi. I'm glad this worked for you :) Please see my edit for how you can alter the length of the line as you desire

Comment: you are a rockstar =D

Comment: If you insist :) :) !